# HTML/Javascript: access to geolocation from local HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to implement a web page which displays your location on a map. Given that the person accessing the web page may not have internet access, I want the web page to be a local HTML file.

These days, for security reasons, it doesn't seem to be possible to access geolocation form a local HTML file.

Any ideas as to how I can get access to geolocation from a local HTML file?

Thanks

I have tried accessing my local HTML file via a local web server but these only allow http pages whereas geolocation seems to be dependent upon an https file.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. It also misses details. A web server does not the ability to change the local file of a browser. It would be a huge security issue if a webserver could change users' local files. This is also not how the web stack works. If a user tries to visit a website and the browser sends a GET request to the web server. The Webserver then hopefully will RETURN the HTML file where requested. If you have no internet then you cannot send a GET request. Also, a Server does not know if a user will have no internet in the future.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you trying to develop an app, not an actual web application. which as said above would bring us back to missing details and clarity. How does the local file exist in the first place? What geolocations do you mean in which context?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your responses. Sorry that I was not clear. I am trying to build a web application, not an app. I would create the local HTML file. By geolocation, I mean the lat and long returned by (eg) navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know why you think that I want the web server to change the local file - I don't. The reason I tried accessing the local HTML file via a local web server was that when I executed the local HTML file directly, trying to get geolocation returned an error. I think that this is because geolocation is not allowed for a local HTML file. However accessing through the local HTML file via a local web server didn't work either because geolocation requires https and the  local web servers that I have found only support http.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, I want the HTML file to be local so that if the internet is not available, quite likely as I'll be using the maps in the countryside, I can still run the web application

Answer (score 1):

To use Geolocation API your application should run on HTTPS protocol or on the localhost web server. Otherwise, Geolocation API will not work.
Most of all you will get the coordinates of your internet provider stations :)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

      function showPosition(position) {
        console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
      }
```

Comment: I think that my application will only work when accessed via a localhost web server if the https protocol is used. However I haven't been able to find a local web server which supports https. If you know of one, please let me know

Comment: the only difference between https and http is the SSL certificate. If you use an actual web-server such as XAMPP locally you can fake that certificate.

Comment: Thanks tacoshy. Can you point me at instructions to fake the certificate?

Answer (score -2):

```html
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>

<script>
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "\nLongitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will not work in a `file:///` URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).